# Flatten nested object with lodash or es6 javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object that originally looks like this

```js
{
  foo: {
    fruit: "watermelon",
    vege: "celery",
  },
  bar: {
    fruit: "banana",
    candy: "snickers",
    drink: "coke",
  },
  ...
}
```

but want to "flatten" and have it look like this

```js
{
  fruit: "banana",
  vege: "celery",
  candy: "snickers",
  drink: "coke",
}
```

If there's an overlap in the sub-object keys, just overwrite the previous one.

What's a sane way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grab the values of your object using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and then use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/assign) with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge all the objects together:

```js
const obj = { foo: { fruit: "watermelon", vege: "celery", }, bar: { fruit: "banana", candy: "snickers", drink: "coke", } };

const res = Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(obj));
console.log(res);
```

With lodash you can use the corresponding methods `_.assign()` and `_.values()`:

```js
const obj = { foo: { fruit: "watermelon", vege: "celery", }, bar: { fruit: "banana", candy: "snickers", drink: "coke", } };

const res = _.assign({}, ..._.values(obj));
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Both of these methods rely on the iteration order that `Object.values()` and `for...in` uses. In the latest spec this is something which can be relied on, but this hasn't always been the case. If you need to read the values in a guaranteed order 100% of the time, you can consider specifying the order of keys using an array:

```js
const obj = { foo: { fruit: "watermelon", vege: "celery", }, bar: { fruit: "banana", candy: "snickers", drink: "coke", } };

const order = ["foo", "bar"]; // visit foo first then bar
const res = Object.assign({}, ...order.map(k => obj[k]));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you can use `_.values()` that generates an array, and then spread to `_.merge()`. I'm using `_.flow()` to generate a function that does that:

```js
const fn = _.flow(_.values, _.spread(_.merge))

const obj = {
  foo: {
    fruit: "watermelon",
    vege: "celery",
  },
  bar: {
    fruit: "banana",
    candy: "snickers",
    drink: "coke",
  },
}

const result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get values of object using `Object.prototype.values` and using `Array.prototype.forEach`, you can get the merge the object `[key, value]` pairs as follows.

```js
const input = {
  foo: {
    fruit: "watermelon",
    vege: "celery",
  },
  bar: {
    fruit: "banana",
    candy: "snickers",
    drink: "coke",
  }
};

let output = {};
Object.values(input).forEach((item) => {
  output = {
    ...output,
    ...item
  };
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = {
  foo: {
    fruit: "watermelon",
    vege: "celery",
  },
  bar: {
    fruit: "banana",
    candy: "snickers",
    drink: "coke",
  },
}

var result = {}
Object.values(input).forEach(item => {
  result = {
    ...result,
    ...item
  }
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take two function for getting a flat object from multi nested objects.

The outer gets from an array of objects a flat object and the recursinve function returns a flat array with object for every level.

```js
const
    flat = data => Object.assign({}, ...pairs(data)),
    pairs = o => o && typeof o === 'object' && Object
        .entries(o)
        .flatMap(([k, v]) => pairs(v) || { [k]: v }),
    data = { 
        foo: {
            fruit: "watermelon",
            vege: "celery"
        },
        bar: {
            fruit: "banana",
            candy: "snickers",
            drink: "coke"
        },
        n: {
            m: {
                o: {
                    p: 42
                }
            }
        }
    },
    result = flat(data);

console.log(result);
```